# How to put numbers in parenthesis in the S column using siunitx package

Tags: tables, siunitx, tabularx, ctable

In the following minimal code, when I replace the `l` columns by `S` I get an error message saying

```
invalid-number!! Invalid numerical input '(4.36)'.!!
See the siunitx documentation for further information.!!
```

It goes on.  It is important that I put the numbers in the third and fifth columns in parenthesis.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ctable}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\ctable[
     caption = {caption here},
     label = {tab:tab1},
     pos = {!ht},
     center
] {@{}lS@{\enskip}>{(}l<{)}S@{\enskip}>{(}l<{)}}{
    \tnote[$\dagger$]{footnote here}
}{ \FL
\multirow{2}{*}{var} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Title here} \\
\cmidrule{2-5}
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{[AA]} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{[BB]} \ML       
$var_{12}$ & 1.37 & 4.36 & 1.50 & 8.91  \\
$var_{13}$ & 1.73 & 8.43 & 1.84 & 10.88 
\LL}
\end{document}
```

Comment: try `parse-numbers=false`, numbers in `(...)` need to have a special format with `siunitx` as in `1.23(45)`, `(4.36)` does not follow this rule, thus the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two things we should be careful about.

1. parenthesis are used to indicate the uncertainty through the `table-figures-uncertainty` macro
2. We can use `table-parse-only` to get the `parsing` only feature.

For item 1 above, we can hide `(` and `)` from `siunitx` by using braces → `{(}` and `{)}` so that they are not meant to indicate the uncertainty. `table-parse-only` gives correct spacing.

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ctable}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{multirow}
%\sisetup{detect-weight=true,table-space-text-pre={(},table-space-text-post={)}}

\begin{document}
\ctable[
     caption = {caption here},
     label = {tab:tab1},
     pos = {!ht},
     center
] {@{}lS@{\enskip}>{{(}}S[table-parse-only]<{{)}}S@{\enskip}>{{(}}S[table-parse-only]<{{)}}}{
    \tnote[$\dagger$]{footnote here}
}{ \FL
\multirow{2}{*}{var} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Title here} \\
\cmidrule{2-5}
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{[AA]} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{[BB]} \ML
$var_{12}$ & 1.37 & 4.36 & 1.50 & 8.91  \\
$var_{13}$ & 1.73 & 8.43 & 1.84 & 10.88
\LL}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just a side question, if I have another column beneath such as
$var_4$ & \multicolumn{2}{*}{23.568} & \multicolumn{2}{*}{3.988}
the S column does not recognize the last two cell entries as numbers. Is there a way to go about this?

Comment: @Duna When you use `\multicolumn` things are over ridden.

Answer (score 7):

Instead of providing the option `table-parse-only` to the `siunitx` package, you could also provide the -- in my opinion less intrusive -- option `input-symbols = ()`. Doing so tells `siunitx` to treat the symbols `(` and `)` as ordinary inputs, i.e., not to assign any special meaning to them (such as denoting uncertainty...).

Two nice features of this approach are (i) you needn't do anything special in the header information of the `tabular` environment in order to enter the parentheses in the body of the table and (ii) the ability of the `siunitx` package to align numbers on their decimal points (and to perform any other parsing tasks) is not affected.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}
\sisetup{input-symbols = ()} % "(" and ")" are ordinary inputs
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht!]
\caption{caption here} \label{tab:tab1}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}lSSSS@{}}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{4}{c}{Title here} \\
\cmidrule{2-5}
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{[AA]} & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{[BB]} \\
\midrule
$var_{12}$ & 1.37 & (4.36) & 1.50 &  (8.91)\\
$var_{13}$ & 1.73 & (8.43) & 1.84 & (10.88)\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is a very nice idea! But while the numbers in parenthesis are aligned correctly, rounding seems to be ignored.  i.e. setting `round-precision=1` is correctly applied to columns 2 and 4 but not columns 3 and 5 (which keep their original number of decimals places).  Do you know why?

Comment: @Donna - (By the way, I assume you also set the option `round-mode=places`.) The package's user guide says, on page 22, that "No rounding will take place if the number contains an
uncertainty component". Uncertainty components can be stated, inter alia, as numbers in parentheses. This working assumption appears to apply in columns 3 and 5 even though the option `input-symbols = ()` has been set. You may want contact the package's maintainer -- his email address is given at the bottom of page 1 of the package's user guide -- and raise your question directly with him.

Comment: Yes I also set `round-mode=places`.   But I also recently wanted to include numbers in parens to indicate a percentage, and ran into similar issues.   I  found a work-around using `round` from the FP package : `\FPeval{\x}{round(4.36:1)}{(}\x)`  (no idea why why the first paren needs to be enclosed in `{}`. )

Answer (score 1):

As a comment to @Donna's comment in @Mico's post (no rep yet...), you can place the parens in curly braces, and rounding will still occur.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}
\sisetup{input-symbols = ()} % "(" and ")" are ordinary inputs
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht!]
\caption{caption here} \label{tab:tab1}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}lSSSS@{}}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{4}{c}{Title here} \\
\cmidrule{2-5}
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{[AA]} & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{[BB]} \\
\midrule
$var_{12}$ & 1.3723 & {(}4.3646{)} & 1.5045 &  {(}8.9111{)}\\
$var_{13}$ & 1.7343 & {(}8.4365{)} & 1.8445 & {(}10.8888{)}\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Any idea how to avoid the whitespace in front of the number in parantheses and the negative side effects of `table-parse-only`?