# siunitx: Adding brackets to numbers breaks last column

Tags: tables, tabularx, siunitx

When putting round brackets around the numbers in all odd columns, in the very last column a weird horizontal space is included:

[image]

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{Actual values of parameters and derivation from ideal values in brackets.}
\sisetup{
    table-align-text-pre = true,
    table-align-text-post = true,
    input-open-uncertainty = ,
    input-close-uncertainty = ,
    retain-explicit-plus
    }
 \setlength{\tabcolsep}{5pt}
 \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}X*5{S[table-format=3]@{}>{(}S[table-format=-2, table-space-text-pre=(, table-space-text-post=)]<{)}}@{}} 
&  \multicolumn{2}{c}{g+g+tg+g+} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{g+ttg$-$g$-$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{g+g+ttg$-$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{g+g$-$ttg+} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{g+g$-$tg$-$g$-$} \\ \hline
\bfseries 1 & 301 & +1  & 296 & +4  & 300 & +0  & 297 & -3  & 296 & -4  \\ 
\bfseries 2 & 279 & -21 & 149 & -31 & 278 & -22 & 105 & +45 & 113 & +53 \\ 
\bfseries 3 & 173 & -7  & 185 & +5  & 174 & -6  & 182 & +2  & 187 & +7  \\ 
\bfseries 4 & 303 & +3  &  49 & -11 & 247 & +67 & 142 & -38 &  73 & +13 \\ 
\bfseries 5 & 301 & +1  &  59 & -1  &  61 & +1  & 294 & -6  &  64 & +4  \\ 
 \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Why is the closing bracket in the last column pushed to the right, and how do I make it look like the rest of the columns?
I do want to have the parenthesis to be aligned, unfortunately none of the answers to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170486/how-to-put-numbers-in-parenthesis-in-the-s-column-using-siunitx-package) gives the desired result.

Using `\sisetup{input-symbols = ()}` raises numerous `Misplaced sign token` errors, and putting the round brackets inside curly brackets (`>{{(}}` instead of `>{(}`) does not have any effect.

Comment: Which `siunitx` version are you using? Mine (v3.0.49) looks correct.

Comment: @daleif Oh, interesting, I have 2.8c, which is the most recent one provided by Opensuse Tumbleweed… So is there any hope for a solution, or do I need to wait for the update to trickle down?

Comment: You'll probably wait for a long time, linux dists are not knwo to keep their LaTeX versions updated. Version 3 has been out for quite some time. I normally install Upstream TeXLive instead (see tug.org/texlive), then I can get updates independently of the linux dist.

Comment: Tumbleweed finally provided the update for siunitx version 3 and now everything works fine!